# Force membership sign-ups to register as user

Tags: wordpress, civimember, contribution-page, user-account, registration

As the title already says, I am trying to create a WordPress user for each person paying a membership fee.

Therefore I already checked the *Anyone can register* box in the WordPress settings.

What it should look like:

1. a person navigates to my site where the signup form (contribution page) is displayed (this works so far)
2. when he signs up he has to register as a user (so insert a password and username) - this part doesnt work so far there is only the email field and the billing fields.

Can somebody help me to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Profile, in the Advanced Settings (at least for Drupal) there is an option to 'require user account creation'. So if you have this selected in the Profile, and then set that Profile to show on your Membership page then I would expect anyone completing the form to create a user account.

Answer (score 0):

i just managed to do create a contribution page with a forced user sign up.

My problem now: i dont know what i configured different i compared every field with the other page and everything is the same. 
Also i tried to create another page with user sign up but there it again doesnt work.

I dont know how to solve this problem -.-

I know i can duplicate the page but i want to set up wordpress on a new server once i know how to configure civicrm and therefore i need to know how to configure that signup ...

Has anybody an idea?

[image]

Comment: just in case this helps: you won't see the username/password boxes if you're logged in - check the form from a different browser to be sure they're not appearing.

Answer (score -1):

you probably need to build a CiviCRM extension / WordPress plugin for this.

1. In the buildForm hook add a new field for username and password.
2. In the post hook take these details and create a user.

Reply here if you need further help,

Comment: Hey 
thanks for your quick reply :)
i read that it should be possible without any plugins to force people to sign up as user
Or is there an other way to realize my problem (doesnt have to be a contrbution page) 
requirements: someone pays 50$ is added to a group and has to create a user
THX!